# Transfer multiple emails from an IMAP server to GMail?

Tags: gmail, imap, gmail-imap

Is there a good way of transfering an IMAP directory structure and their emails to GMail? (imap)

I moved from my own IMAP server to Google Apps Business earlier this week and I'd need to transfer a ton of emails. I can't seem to find a good way of doing it.

I thought it would be possible via POP3 but how could I keep the directory structure?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: Setup both inboxes then simply right click the email and paste into the new inbox

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do is simply drag and drop the directories from my imap first account to the gmail one and it worked using both OSX Mail.app and Outlook.